# How to detect text/logo-details from an image of any consumer product?

Tags: image, imagemagick, text-recognition, python-tesseract

I am trying to detect name of any consumer product from an image of its packaging.For eg- [Maggie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fnUE.jpg) (I want to detect- Maggie happiness is homemade) [Kellogg's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cweis.jpg)

I have tried applying image prepossessing(e.g- erosion, open, close etc.) and then supplying that pre-processed image to pytesseract(OCR). I am planning to use Image-Magic tool if it can do any help.

Would just pre-processing of an image be enough, if not then what should I do?(Any code, software anything)

PS- I dont want to use Google Vision or anything similar API

Comment: @Abid Rahman K can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Imagemagick 6, you can do the following to isolate the "kelloggs".

```
fill back to replace everything but the red color
fill white to replace the red color

convert kellogg.jpg -fuzz 15% \
-fill black +opaque "rgb(240,0,0)" \
-fill white -opaque "rgb(240,0,0)" \
result.png
```

[image]

For your "maggie" image, it is a bit more complicated, since you have yellow for "maggie" and yellow elsewhere.

```
fill yellow color to replace the white in the corners
fill yellow color to replace black
floodfill the outside yellow with black
fill black to replace everything but yellow
fill white to replace yellow

convert maggie.jpg \
-fuzz 15% -fill "rgb(254,242,0)" -opaque white \
-fuzz 20% -fill "rgb(254,242,0)" -opaque black \
-fuzz 15% -fill black -draw "color 10,10 floodfill" -alpha off \
-fuzz 15% -fill black +opaque "rgb(254,242,0)" \
-fuzz 15% -fill white -opaque "rgb(254,242,0)" \
result2.png
```

[image]

But there is the trademark left. So to remove that we add connected components processing to filter out the smallest white areas.

```
convert maggie.jpg \
-fuzz 15% -fill "rgb(254,242,0)" -opaque white \
-fuzz 20% -fill "rgb(254,242,0)" -opaque black \
-fuzz 15% -fill black -draw "color 10,10 floodfill" -alpha off \
-fuzz 15% -fill black +opaque "rgb(254,242,0)" \
-fuzz 15% -fill white -opaque "rgb(254,242,0)" \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=50 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 4 \
result3.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!